# Getting Value from td

Tags: jquery

My Code of take first element, I need the second and Third element, how can i do that?

```
$(".button").click(function(){    
    var value=$(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method like following.

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    var tds = $(this).closest('tr').find('td');

    var first = tds.eq(0).text();
    var second = tds.eq(1).text();
    var third = tds.eq(2).text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give like this

```
$(".button").click(function(){    
       var second=$(this).closest('tr').children('td:nth-child(2)').text();
       var third=$(this).closest('tr').children('td:nth-child(3)').text();
       console.log(seond + " "+third);
 });
```